How can I perform a SUM window function with a time range but handle duplicate timestamps row-wise in SQL
I have a scenario where I need to calculate a running total using the SUM window function in SQL. The issue arises because some rows have duplicate timestamps, and the RANGE clause in the window function groups all rows with the same timestamp together, causing incorrect calculations.
Here’s an example of the SQL I’m trying to use:
SUM(volume) OVER (
    PARTITION BY ID
    ORDER BY td.timestamp
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '60' SECOND PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) AS total_volume

Problem:

When there are duplicate timestamps, the RANGE function groups all entries with the same timestamp into the same window, leading to unexpected results.
I need to process the rows individually (row-wise) within the same timestamp.

Constraints:

I can't add any slight noise in timestamp column, as it will change my time window. It is to be calculate in precision.

Is there a way to adjust the SQL to process rows correctly within the same timestamp range while adhering to the time window logic?
Input



timestamp
Volume




2024-11-16 08:00:00
10


2024-11-16 08:00:00
20


2024-11-16 08:01:00
30


2024-11-16 08:02:00
40


2024-11-16 08:02:00
50



Current Result (Using RANGE and Grouping by Timestamp)



timestamp
RollVolume




2024-11-16 08:00:00
30


2024-11-16 08:00:00
30


2024-11-16 08:01:00
30


2024-11-16 08:02:00
90


2024-11-16 08:02:00
90



Expected Output



timestamp
RollVolume




2024-11-16 08:00:00
10


2024-11-16 08:00:00
30


2024-11-16 08:01:00
30


2024-11-16 08:02:00
40


2024-11-16 08:02:00
90



Here, The RollVolume is calculated row by row within each timestamp, instead of grouping rows with identical timestamps.

in you query you have used partition by ID, but your input data does not have ID, can you correct the input data format and also check if the expected output is correct?

Please tag which DBMS you're using. (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc)

Note: if two rows have the same timestamp, they both happen within 0s of each other. SQL data sets have no implicit ordering, which means that in your data the volume=10 row doesn't occur "before" the volume=20 row (or vice versa). You'd have to assert something like the lowest volume row happens first.

Hey @samhita , the input data I provided intentionally does not include an ID column, as the operation is meant to be carried out within a specific partition (e.g., ID) and the data given is for only for one specific ID. This means that the rolling calculation should respect both the time-based window (last 60 seconds) and the implicit partitioning by ID.

Hey @MatBailie The data represents events that occur at the same exact timestamp, and their order cannot be determined inherently or by any secondary attribute rather we assume that rows those rows itself has some order . Introducing an assumption (e.g., the lowest volume occurs first) would be arbitrary and could lead to inaccurate calculation. My requirement is to calculate the rolling total strictly based on timestamps within a 60-second window, processing the rows row by row as they appear in the dataset without introducing assumptions about implicit ordering.

As I already said; SQL rows have no order. Your belief that rows exist "row by row as they appear in the dataset" is false. This is strictly impossible without additional columns to include in an ORDER BY clause.

You also still haven't tagged which DBMS you're using.

It is safe to assume that your table has an unproven column in the question that determines the order of entries. For example, some auto-increment column. Otherwise, you will not be able to deterministically determine the order of the rows. You can try row_number()over(...) to determine the order of the rows and hope for the best.

As everyone mentioned, without knowing ordering of data it would not be possible to retrieve the output, because select does not guarantee it will output in insertion order, unless you have a column to determine it.And every calculation done on grouping similar timestamp could lead to different output in different runs.

I must admit, I'm not sure which DBMS I'm working with. Everything is set up on a Jupyter server using Python, and the underlying database management is handled behind the scenes. I'm running this code in a Python notebook. There is a column for the order sequence of rows, but when I tried to use it in the ORDER BY clause, I encountered an error. The error was something like: 'ORDER BY in PARTITION BY clause can only have one column,' or something similar.

Show the additional column (for a complete [mre]) and I'll show you the answer for PostgreSQL.

The simplest option is to run a cumulative sum from start to finish, without the time RANGE, then use a second cumulative sum to deduct the unwanted rows, with the time RANGE...
This ensures you can use an id column to enforce an ordering without running into errors when trying to use RANGE BETWEEN.
It also ensures the you only include rows "> 60s ago" rather than rows ">= 60s ago".
Performance wise, it only scans the data once, avoiding the cost of correlated sub-queries.
CREATE TABLE example (
  id    BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  x     INT, 
  ts    TIMESTAMP,
  val   INT
) 


CREATE TABLE


INSERT INTO
  example (x, ts, val)
VALUES
  (1, '2024-11-16 08:00:00',    10),
  (1, '2024-11-16 08:00:00',    20), 
  (1, '2024-11-16 08:01:00',    30),
  (1, '2024-11-16 08:02:00',    40), 
  (1, '2024-11-16 08:02:00',    50) 


INSERT 0 5


SELECT
  *, 
  SUM(val)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY x
          ORDER BY ts, id
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
  -
  COALESCE(
    SUM(val)
      OVER (
         PARTITION BY x
             ORDER BY ts
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '60' SECOND PRECEDING
    )
    ,
    0
  )
    AS rolling_total 
FROM
  example





id
x
ts
val
rolling_total




1
1
2024-11-16 08:00:00
10
10


2
1
2024-11-16 08:00:00
20
30


3
1
2024-11-16 08:01:00
30
30


4
1
2024-11-16 08:02:00
40
40


5
1
2024-11-16 08:02:00
50
90




SELECT 5


fiddle

Thanks for your answer but unfortunately
''' SUM(val)
OVER (
PARTITION BY x
ORDER BY ts, id
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)''' at this part it raise me error saying ORDER BY in partition can't take two argument or something. It might work with other DBMS. Thank you for attention.

@SaurabhGhadge Always include the exact error message. (It may help determine which DBMS you're using, an is critical to resolving the issue. For example, that error may indicate a typo, where you have RANGE BETWEEN instead of ROWS BETWEEN by mistake.)

As mentioned in the comments, deterministic row ordering is required for accurate results. The below uses PostgreSQL's ctid which represents the physical location of each row in a table but can change with table updates.
https://dbfiddle.uk/xxm_Ujpm
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp, Volume, ctid) AS rn
    FROM input
)
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp, Volume, ctid) AS rn
    FROM input
)
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp, Volume, ctid) AS rn
    FROM input
)
SELECT
    o1.timestamp,
    (
        SELECT SUM(o2.Volume)
        FROM ordered o2
        WHERE o2.timestamp > o1.timestamp - INTERVAL '60 seconds'
          AND o2.timestamp <= o1.timestamp
          AND ( 
              o2.timestamp < o1.timestamp 
              OR (o2.timestamp = o1.timestamp AND o2.rn <= o1.rn) 
          )
    ) AS RollVolume
FROM ordered o1
ORDER BY o1.timestamp, o1.rn;



What about a row that's 59.001 seconds earlier?

https://dbfiddle.uk/08w8Gtk3

@MatBailie - Thank you. Updated precision: > o1.timestamp - INTERVAL '60 seconds' and <= o1.timestamp....

hey @keithwalsh I tried something similar solution to this and it worked for me. Now, I can't use partition which results in longer processing time but I am able to get results. Thank you for insights into this, really appreciated it.
